# Sql Query is 20 times slower when adding where clause on Row_number() value row

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

It's a simple search on full-text query

```
WITH xx AS
( 
    SELECT   
        kh.* ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY kh.Id ) AS RowNo
    FROM     
        KhachHang kh
    WHERE    
        CONTAINS (kh.Ten, 'hoang and van and ngan')
        AND kh.TrangThai = 1
)
SELECT xx.* 
FROM xx
```

The problems only appear when a `Where` clause is added

```
WITH xx AS
( 
    SELECT   
        kh.* ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY kh.Id ) AS RowNo
    FROM     
        KhachHang kh
    WHERE    
        CONTAINS (kh.Ten, 'hoang and van and ngan')
        AND kh.TrangThai = 1
)
SELECT xx.* 
FROM xx
--- This is key that create the difference       
WHERE xx.RowNo > 0 AND xx.RowNo <= 100
```

This difference make the latter query run about 20 times slower.

I checked the execution plan and notice the difference between an Index Seek and Scan. But even I changed the latter with a WITH FORCESEEK, the result is similar.

The number of records is 8 millions in my production database.

[Attached execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZhVt.png)

Any help and suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your select, put it into temp table and make index over RowNo column, first thing you should do

Comment: Thanks @Veljko89. Your suggestion did solve the problem. But you add it as comment so I can't raise it answer.

Comment: It's fine ... just glad to help out. Good luck in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a temp table instead of a CTE. So put the whole table or a few fields as you can get away with in the temp table then do the row number search on the temp table.

if the table has a pk then just put the pk and the rowno into the temp table identify the rowno ranges you need then join back to the parent to get the details.

you can add a non clustered index on the temp table (after you fill it) on the rowno column if you find performance is still bad.

Comment: Your suggestion did boost-up the performance. It hope you can give some detailed explanation on why?? Thanks.

Comment: without seeing the plans its hard to tell, one possibility is that the CTE could be in memory i.e. it will get a high memory grant for the CTE to hold the rows in memory whilst it carrys out the row number operation. Whereas with the temp table its on disk so less memory is needed. Worth keeping an eye on page life expectancy when you run the cte and check the memory grants via the actual execution plan